# Quoting variable in application call

Tags: bash, quotations

I'm trying to run an application that needs a parameter passed in single or double quotes:

`bwa mem -R '@RG\tID:foo\tLB=foo\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=bar'` `...`

I'm trying to run this in a script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash

var=foo_bar
first=$(echo $var | cut -d '_' -f 1)
second=$(echo $var | cut -d '_' -f 2)

readgroup="@RG\tID:$first\tLB=HUM\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=$second"

echo \'$readgroup\'
```

---

```
'@RG\tID:foo\tLB=HUM\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=bar'
```

---

However, when I use this as a parameter in my application call:

```
var=foo_bar
first=$(echo $var | cut -d '_' -f 1)
second=$(echo $var | cut -d '_' -f 2)

readgroup="@RG\tID:$first\tLB=HUM\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=$second"

bwa mem -R \'$readgroup\' ...
```

it's interpreted as

`\'@RG\tID:HUM-7\tLB=HUM\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=HUM-7\'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The application doesn't care about the quotes; they are only used to protect the string from the shell.

```
var=foo_bar
IFS=_ read first second <<< "$var"

readgroup="@RG\tID:$first\tLB=HUM\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=$second"

bwa mem -R "$readgroup"
```

If the `\t` are actually supposed to be literal tab characters, consider using `printf` instead of an assignment statement.

```
printf -v readgroup '@RG\tID:%s\tLB=HUM\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=%s' "$first" "$second"
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like:

```
readgroup="'@RG\tID:$first\tLB=HUM\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=$second'" [with '' wrapping]

readgroup="@RG\tID:$first\tLB=HUM\tPL=illumina\tPU=1234.1\tSM=$second" [without]
```

Important thing is to use `-e` option for echo [ See `man echo` ]

```
echo -e $readgroup
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying to use the variable as input for another program - how can I use `echo -e` in this case?